# Differentiability of convolution of not compactly supported functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convolution

I searched for similiar posts, but haven't found any answer. Suppose we have two $C^2$ functions $f$ and $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that the convolution $f\star g$ is well defined in every point. Can we then say something about the regularity of the convolution $f \star g$? $f$ and $g$ are not compactly supported. I would be thankful for any reference.